# How to pass a 'bound' value to a dependency property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

My application has a MainWindow. Within this, there is 1 control, a `ListBox`, binding to a property of the MainWindowViewModel. This property is a UserControl, of type CriteriaVm

CriteriaVm has a single string property called MyString

Within the Criteria View I have the following code

```
<UserControl x:Class="CompoundInterests.View.CriteriaView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CompoundInterests.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Dictionary.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border>
            <Expander Header="{Binding MyString}" >
                <vm:PropertiesVm ThresholdName="{Binding MyString}" />
            </Expander>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see, I'm binding MyString in 2 places. The binding in the Expander works fine, the one in the vm:PropertiesVm does not (which is using Dependency Properites).  The following error shows in the Output window

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=MyString; DataItem=null; target element is 'PropertiesVm' (HashCode=5991653); target property is 'ThresholdName' (type 'String')

OK the error message tells me it's looking for MyString in ProperitesVm ... I should be looking for MyString in CriteriaVm. This means I need to use RelativeSource I think, which is up 1 level and of type UserControl. So I updated to:

```
<vm:PropertiesVm ThresholdName="{Binding Path=MyString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=UserControl,Mode=FindAncestor}}" />
```

I get a slightly different issue but it appears as if the same underlying fault exists

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=MyString; DataItem=null; target element is 'PropertiesVm' (HashCode=24649639); target property is 'ThresholdName' (type 'String')

At the moment, PropertiesVm only has the dependency properties, the PropertiesView is just an empty grid. This is so I can work on this error first and worry about the next stage of binding later.

I don't see why I'm getting the error message or what I'm doing wrong. 
I can happily provide more code if needed. The project at this stage is very early, as such, minimal code.

Comment: 1.Add [BindableAttribute(true)] attribute to ThresholdName property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the message!

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=MyString; DataItem=null; target element is 'PropertiesVm' (HashCode=5991653); target property is 'ThresholdName' (type 'String')

From what I understood is, because my UserControl inherited DependencyObject and not UserControl it was not a UIElement...

Therefore, I had to move the Dependency Properties to the codebehind of my View, which allowed the two way binding to work but kept the datacontext of my ViewModel in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the view to look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ns:YourViewModel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ns:YourViewModel}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThresholdName, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The view model code would be pretty much unchanged from what you've shown:

```
public class YourViewModel: Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThreshNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ThresholdName", typeof(string), typeof(PropertiesVm), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string ThresholdName
    {
        get { return GetValue(ThreshNameProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(ThreshNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

You weren't totally clear about what "MyStringValue" is so I'd expect it to be a normal property of the MainWindow.  MainWindow would create an instance of your control, setting "ThresholdName" to this "MyStringValue" property:

```
<Grid>
    <ns:YourViewModel ThresholdName="{Binding MyStringValue}"/>
</Grid>
```

Finally your MainWindow code would be:

```
public string MyStringValue { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    MyStringValue = "dog";
}
```

Comment: I'm lost with your example - you are using a ControlTemplate, essentially overwritting what is already there. This isn't the goal :S

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your inheritance from DependencyObject to FrameworkElement, this should work.

```
<vm:PropertiesVm DataContext="{Binding}" ThresholdName="{Binding MyString}" />
```

Anyway, have you tried Attached property?

I guess this one is similar one way or another.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aff23943-5483-40b2-816b-4ce687bc6bf8/systemwindowsdata-error-2-cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement?forum=wpf